# MVC using Spring hello world example

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement the hello world example using Spring MVC but it is not giving the desired result.

This is my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Print: ${message} world</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.sbv.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LoginSpringMVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloServlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.sbv.controller" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

The output which I am getting is

Print: world

The ${message} is not getting printed

Someone please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure you are delivering the right view: Could you add some text to your jsp file and verify it's displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message` attribute is added to the `MODEL` in the `printHello` method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

which will get executed when you make a `GET` request for `/hello (http://host:port/appContext/hello)`. But you have the below entry in `web.xml` file:

```
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

and the web container will use this file for appending to a request for `/` to show `index.jsp` to the user, as you don't have any handler method mapped to `/` URL. So, in order to show the message to the user, remove the `<welcome-file-list>` entry from `web.xml` and change `HelloController` to this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

And make your request to

```
http://yourhost:yourport/YourApp/hello
```

to match your `@Controller` mapping.

If you make your request to

```
http://yourhost:yourport/YourApp
```

and any of the `<welcome-file>` entries exist, those will be chosen before your `Servlet` is hit.